# How can I use `sed` to replace the single quotes enclosing a directory with double quotes

Tags: regex, unix, sed, aix

### What I want to achieve:

Suppose I have a file `file` with the following content:

```
ENV_VAR='/foo/`whoami`/bar/'
sh my_script.sh 'LOL'
```

I want to replace - using `sed` - the *single quotes* that surrounds the directory names, but not the ones that surrounds stuff that does not seem like a directory, for example, the arguments of a script.

That is, after running the `sed` command, I would expect the following output:

```
ENV_VAR="/foo/`whoami`/bar/"
sh my_script.sh 'LOL'
```

The idea is to make this happen without  using `tr` to replace `'` with `"`, nor `sed` like `s/'/"/g`, as I don't want to replace the lines that does not seem to be directories.

Please note that `sed` is running on `AIX`, so no `GNU sed` is available.

### What I have tried:

If I use `sed` like this:

```
sed "s;'=.*/.*';&;g" file
```

... the `&` variable hold the regex previously matched, that is: `` ='/foo/`whoami`/bar/' ``.  However, I can't figure out how to make the replacement so the *single quotes* gets transformed into *double quotes*.

I wonder if there's a way to make this work using `sed` only, via a one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

`/usr/bin/sed -e "/='.*\/.*'/ s/'/\"/g" file`

Basically, you just want the plain ' => " replacement, but not for all lines, just for those that match the pattern `='.*\/.*'/`. And, in the s command you just need to escape the ".

Comment: So, you can use `s/x/y/g` as the replace-with part in the *"outer"* `sed`?  That's new to me!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
sed "s/'\(.*\/.*\)'/\"\1\"/g"
```

Captures the part between `'` and uses a backreference.